# All Possible Matrices from Pasting Small Matrices into a Big Matrix

Tags: r, list

Given a matrix M and smaller matrices with different possible values, I seek to list all possible matrices resulting from superimposing combinations of these small matrices into the matrix M. The small matrices are to be inserted in the locations of M having the same row/column names.

For instance, say have:

```
 M <- matrix(rep(0, 49), nrow =7, ncol =7)
 rownames(M) <- colnames(M) <-seq(1,7)
 > M
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

# Generate first set of small matrices:
sub_mat_1_1 <- matrix(rep(1, 9), nrow =3, ncol =3)
rownames(sub_mat_1_1) <- colnames(sub_mat_1_1) <- c(2,3,5)
sub_mat_1_2 <- matrix(rep(2, 9), nrow =3, ncol =3)
rownames(sub_mat_1_2) <- colnames(sub_mat_1_2) <- c(2,3,5)
sub_mat_1_3 <- matrix(rep(3, 9), nrow =3, ncol =3)
rownames(sub_mat_1_3) <- colnames(sub_mat_1_3) <- c(2,3,5)
submatrix_1 <- list(sub_mat_1_1, sub_mat_1_2, sub_mat_1_3)

# Generate second set of small matrices:
submatrix_2 <- list()
sub_mat_2_1 <- matrix(rep(1, 4), nrow =2, ncol =2)
rownames(sub_mat_2_1) <- colnames(sub_mat_2_1) <- c(1,6)
sub_mat_2_2 <- matrix(rep(2, 4), nrow =2, ncol =2)
rownames(sub_mat_2_2) <- colnames(sub_mat_2_2) <- c(1,6)
submatrix_2 <- list(sub_mat_2_1, sub_mat_2_2)

# Generate list of small matrices:
submatrices <- list()
submatrices[[1]] <- submatrix_1
submatrices[[2]] <- submatrix_2

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  2 3 5
2 1 1 1
3 1 1 1
5 1 1 1

[[1]][[2]]
  2 3 5
2 2 2 2
3 2 2 2
5 2 2 2

[[1]][[3]]
  2 3 5
2 3 3 3
3 3 3 3
5 3 3 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  1 6
1 1 1
6 1 1

[[2]][[2]]
  1 6
1 2 2
6 2 2
```

Since there are 3 possibilities for the first small matrix set and 2 for the second, I seek to output, without using a for loop, all 6 possible matrices as a list:

```
[[1]]
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
2 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
3 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
6 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[2]]
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
2 0 2 2 0 2 0 0
3 0 2 2 0 2 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 2 2 0 2 0 0
6 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[3]]
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
2 0 3 3 0 3 0 0
3 0 3 3 0 3 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 3 3 0 3 0 0
6 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[4]]
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 0 0 0 0 2 0
2 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
3 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
6 2 0 0 0 0 2 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[5]]
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 0 0 0 0 2 0
2 0 2 2 0 2 0 0
3 0 2 2 0 2 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 2 2 0 2 0 0
6 2 0 0 0 0 2 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[6]]
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 0 0 0 0 2 0
2 0 3 3 0 3 0 0
3 0 3 3 0 3 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 3 3 0 3 0 0
6 2 0 0 0 0 2 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In general, I may have n given "lists of small matrices", each with its own number of matrices. How would I use an apply type function in this context?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your question has too many ambiguities? I do not see why you consider those 4 matrices (or 6 for that matter) in the list to be an exhaustive enumeration of the "submatrices" of `M`. In fact they do not appear even be true submatrices of `M`, since M is all zeroes.

Comment: I guess my terminology is incorrect then and thanks for letting me know! Simply put: I have a big matrix M and smaller matrices from which I want to generate all possible glueings of combiantions of small matrices into M. My issue is how to carry this out without using for loops.

Comment: You make no reference to whether these glueings need to preserve adjacency of elements or whether the submatrices need to be square. The example you offered is subject to various interpretations but it appears that the sub matrices need to be square, but they can be placed back into the large matrix in non-adjacent locations. All guesswork, since you have not adopted standard mathematical terminology.

Comment: the OP did (I think) answer this in the comment to my question (I haven't gotten around to updating my question): the dimension names of the 'submatrices' identify the positions into which they're to be inserted ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the requested output, but I have to agree with the commenters that the problem is not very well posed.  How do you define the positions into which the values of the submatrices are inserted?  I simply assumed that you wanted them inserted into a particular subset of rows and columns as shown in your requested output ...

A function to insert two matrices into specified rows/columns of `M` (defined globally, probably bad practice)

```
tmpmatf <- function(m1,m2,rc1=c(2,3,5),rc2=c(1,6)) {
    pos1 <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rc1,rc1))
    pos2 <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rc2,rc2))
    M[pos1] <- m1
    M[pos2] <- m2
    M
}
```

Now use `expand.grid` to create a data frame with all combinations of indices from each list of submatrices, and use `alply` (array-to-list) from `plyr` to run `tmpmatf` on each combination:

```
library(plyr)
alply(expand.grid(seq(length(submatrices[[1]])),
                  seq(length(submatrices[[2]]))),
      1,
      function(x) {
          tmpmatf(submatrices[[1]][[x[[1]]]],submatrices[[2]][[x[[2]]]])
      })
```

This should work with an arbitrary number of submatrices in each your two lists of submatrices, but if you really have more (>2) lists of submatrices, then you haven't given us enough information to specify how (e.g.) the third list of submatrices should be pasted into the larger matrix ...

Note that the first part of this (using matrix indexing via a two-column matrix) is a lot faster than using a `for` loop to insert individual elements into the matrix, but the second part (`alply`) is not actually much (any?) faster than a pair of nested `for` loops that iterate over all combinations -- the latter might be clearer/easier to debug in this case ...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will clarify in my question: the small matrices are to be inserted into the matrix M at locations with the same row and column names.